# how to find the value of r?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: circuit diagram]

Should I find the I1 using Kirchhoff's circuit laws ?
This is the answer I found.

[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]

[image: page 3]

Comment: What is I1? The current through R1?

Comment: I am assuming that current directions have been assumed to follow gravity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most difficult task you have here is to solve simultaneous equations! I hope you're up to it! Forgive me if some of this seem patronising, I have no way of knowing what's obvious to you.

I'll give you a guide at how you might derive all those equations, but to start with, I'll redraw the network with some extra annotation to help with the explanations:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVJLK9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first thing to note is that the ground symbols in the original schematic both refer to the same node, so I've drawn that on the right. Both resistors R2 and R3 have their bottom terminals connected together. I've also added a voltage source Vt to represent whatever voltage is between ground and the top node T.

Since components connected in parallel have the same voltage across them, the first, and simplest equation to get from this is:

$$ V_{R2} = V_{R3} $$

Kirchoff's Voltage Law (KVL) is the simple observation that as you journey around a loop, the potential as you travel either rises or falls as you traverse each element. Importantly, when you get back to where you started, you must end up at the same potential you began with, which is a net change in potential of 0. It's the same way you must end up at the same elevation above sea level if you take a walk from the beach, around town, up some hills, down some steps and back to the beach.

Taking a journey from Y, across R2 to X (an increase in potential), across R1 to T (another increase), and across the voltage source Vt back to Y (a decrease), we get this equation:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R2} + V_{R1} - V_T &= 0 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

We can make a similar observation about current, which we call Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL). This is saying that the sum of all currents flowing into some node must equal the sum of all currents leaving it, in the same way that the rate of water flowing into a junction in plumbing must equal the rate that water leaves that junction. KCL is usually stated as "the sum of all currents into and out of a node must be zero".

Here's that law applied to node X, written in both ways:

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{R1} &= I_{R2} + I_{R3} \\ \\
I_{R1} - I_{R2} - I_{R3} &= 0\\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Then we have Ohm's law, \$V = IR\$, which tells us the relationship between current through a resistor, and the voltage across it. We can apply Ohm's law for all three resistors:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R1} &= I_{R1} R_1 \\ \\
V_{R2} &= I_{R2} R_2 \\ \\
V_{R3} &= I_{R3} R_3 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

You are told the total power \$P_T\$ dissipated by the entire network. This requires that you know the power law \$P = IV\$. This total is easy to write, as the sum of all the powers dissipated by each resistor:

$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R1}I_{R1} + V_{R2}I_{R2} + V_{R3}I_{R3} &= P_T \\ \\
&= 400W
\end{aligned}
$$

We are also told:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_1 = 25\Omega \\ \\
I_{R2} = 1A \\ \\
I_{R3} = 1A \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

You now have 7 unknowns: \$R_2\$, \$R_3\$, \$V_{R1}\$, \$V_{R2}\$, \$V_{R3}\$, \$V_T\$, and \$I_{R1}\$, and 7 simultaneous equations, enough to solve for every single unknown.

Go for it, and look out for a "kick yourself obvious" simplification you could have made right from the start. Once you have all these fundamental values, you can calcuate everything else you've been asked to find.

---

This whole problem is very trivial, and with some experience can be solved without having to resort to complete nodal analysis. I think this is why I got downvoted, but I didn't want to solve it for you. But now, with the problem solved in a very formal sense, let's look at some things that can really simplyify the algebra, just for completeness.

By inspection, since R2 and R3 have the same voltage across them, and the same current through them, they must also have equal resistance, and their combined resistance is \$\frac{1}{2}R_2\$. We can redraw the circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCGE0A.png)</sup>

A shortcut we can use for \$R_1\$ is the alternative power law \$P=I^2R\$. The power in R1 is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{R1} &= {I_{R1}}^2 \times R_1 \\ \\
&= 2^2 \times 25\Omega \\ \\
&= 100W
\end{aligned}
$$

Now we can figure out the power in R4, the combined parallel pair R2 &
R3. It must be whatever is left over from the 400W total after accounting for R1:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P_{R4} &= {I_{R4}}^2 \times R_4 \\ \\
400W - 100W &= {I_{R4}}^2 \times R_4 \\ \\
2^2 \times R_4 &= 300W \\ \\
R_4 &= \frac{300W}{4} \\ \\
&= 75\Omega
\end{aligned}
$$

Since \$R_4 = \frac{1}{2}R_2\$, and \$R_2 = R_3\$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
R_2 &= 2R_4 \\ \\
&= 2 \times 75\Omega \\ \\
R_2 &= 150\Omega \\ \\
R_3 &= 150\Omega \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

And the rest is a piece of cake.

Comment: I have done as your guidance i have edited the questions and posted them there. are they ok? Thanks

Comment: @BeverlyEasterling that looks good to me!

Comment: @BeverlyEasterling Now that you've done all that hard work, I've updated my answer to show how you could have approached this, by making some very useful simplifications. With experience, these "tricks" become a lot easier to spot.

Answer (score 2):

yes, Kirchoff's laws are kind of inevitable when analyzing linear electrical networks. That's especially the case here.